# need help in parsing mime subject perl

Tags: perl, mime

I managed to get emails from gmail with their subject contains UTF-8 characters ,

```
Subject: =?utf-8?B?5L2g5aW9IOS9oOWlvQ==?=
```

I searched the interent I found its encoded quoted-printable

I tried using the shown code to decode the subject

```
use MIME::QuotedPrint;

print decode_qp("?utf-8?B?5L2g5aW9IOS9oOWlvQ==?=");
```

but it prints the same message , I also tried removing `?utf-8?` but no use, so can one help me in converting the above subject to utf-8 characters instead of the encoding above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Encode::MIME::Header](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Encode%3A%3AMIME%3A%3AHeader) module, as in

```
$ perl -MEncode -le 'print Encode::encode("utf8", \
  Encode::decode("MIME-Header", "=?utf-8?B?5L2g5aW9IOS9oOWlvQ==?="))'
你好 你好
```

or

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use v5.10.0;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Encode qw/ decode /;

my $subject = "=?utf-8?B?5L2g5aW9IOS9oOWlvQ==?=";

binmode STDOUT, ":encoding(UTF-8)";
say decode "MIME-Header", $subject;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [MIME::Base64](http://p3rl.org/MIME%3a%3aBase64), remove `?utf-8?B?` from the beginning and `?=` from the end:

```
use MIME::Base64;
print decode_base64('5L2g5aW9IOS9oOWlvQ=='), "\n";
```

Comment: ... then ask yourself why this doesn't work if the next message you parse encodes its Subject in ISO-somehing.